# Determine whether a sequence of functions converges uniformly

Tags: uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

The function $f_n(x)=3n^3(x-1/n)^2$ for $x\in[0,2]$ is given, and I need to show whether the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$, which I have determined to be $3x^2$. It's given that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ converges pointwisely, but I'm not sure whether that information is useful in this case, and I'm not sure how to proceed to determine whether it's uniformly convergent or not. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure it is $2n^3(x-\frac{1}{n})^2$? It seems to approach $+\infty$ for any $x \in [0,2]$. Isn't it something like $3(x-\frac{1}{n})^2$?

Comment: Yes, it does say $3n^3(x-1/n)^2$, but another subtask did specify that it's only that for $0 \lt x \le n/2$ and that it's $0$ elsewhere, I didn't mention it here because in that subtask you had to find the integral for $f_n(x)$ and I didn't think that it could be relevant here

Comment: The sequence of functions doesn't converge pointwise, so it can't converge uniformly.

Comment: The task specifically says that it converges pointwisely... I am now seriously concerned about whether the task itself has mistakes

Comment: Also if we consider $0 < x \leq \frac{n}{2}$ it goes to $+\infty$, isn't it $\frac{2}{n}$ ? In this way its pointwise limit would be $0$.

Comment: Oops, yes, you are correct, it is $2/n$

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I thought I figured it out by myself but I'll still appreciate it if you post it! I undeleted it so you can post the answer there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok! So, in the comments we discovered $f_n(x) = 3n^3 (x- \frac{1}{n})^2$ only if $0 < x \leq \frac{2}{n}$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise.

Now this clearly converges pointwisely to $0$. (For any $x>0$ for $n$ big enough $x > \frac{2}{n}$)

But $$ ||f_n-0|| = \sup\limits_{x \in (0,\frac{2}{n}]} |f_n(x)| \geq f_n(\frac{2}{n}) = 3n$$ and thus the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thank you very much, both for the answer and being patient in the comments!